# The time-to-reach-queue has elapsed

Tags: transactions, msmq, messaging

I'm attempting to send a message to a remote private queue from an error queue with powershell.
The code I use looks like this:

```
$msg = $src_q.Peek()
$msg.Label = GetLabelWithoutFailedQueue($msg)
$msg.UseDeadLetterQueue = $true
$msg.UseTracing = $true
$msg.AcknowledgeType = [System.Messaging.AcknowledgeTypes]::NegativeReceive
$msg.TimeToBeReceived = [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(10)
$msg.TimeToReachQueue = [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(10)
$tx = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction
$tx.Begin()
$dest_q.Send($msg, $tx)
$tx.Commit()
```

The message keeps on appearing on the transactional dead letter queue with the class: "The time-to-reach-queue has elapsed."
Anyone's got any idea what could trigger such an error? The queue definitely exists- I do manage to peek it. Also, the reason I get the message from the error queue by peeking is just for testing purposes; I have tried doing the same thing with Receive and the result is the same.

Comment: The error shows that the message could not reach the queue in 10 seconds. The queue may well exist but it doesn't look like dest_q is pointing at it. Look in Computer Management at the outgoing queue and see what the status is. Probably says "waiting to connect".

Comment: The Outgoing queue state is 'connected' and I can't see the message itself. I do see that the Number of messages and Unacknowledged (msgs) shows 9 and when the 10 seconds pass they go down back to 8. Is it possible that these 8 are blocking my outgoing queue?

Comment: Probably should add that the remote queue is on a cluster; I do use the cluster name on on $dest_q when experiencing this issue on sending. When I peek the exact same queue, I do get message that are on the queue. NServiceBus manages to put messages on this queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it appears that the path you provide to the MessageQueue constructor is extremely case sensitive; it's enough that one character is uppercase and needs to be lower that you'll find yourself in a similar situation.

If anyone comes across this, then the correct format is: `FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machine_name\private$\queue_name` FormatName has to be camelcased as I've done here.

Make sure `machine_name` and `queue_name` are correct.